# Sticky list dividers in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to make the jQuery Mobile List divider header be fixed / sticky at the top of the page until the next letter or list divider comes up and takes its place?

I have found already something like this: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/experiments/scrollview/lists-divider.html
but demo doesn't work, and when I had implemented this code, it also doesn't work.

Comment: Your link is now dead :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm searching for a plugin to do the same, also for the list dividers on jquery.mobile.
Found the [Sticky plugin](http://labs.anthonygarand.com/sticky).

It works great on firefox, but dividers does not stick to the top on Chrome or Safari browsers, probably because of the complex menu structure jquery mobile creates.
Will try to figure it out.

Comment: sticky plugin works fine with jquery mobile. You only need to modify the width and z-index

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [jQuery plugin on GitHub](http://github.com/teamdf/jquery-list/). There's also a [showcase article](http://www.teamdf.com/web/showcasing-jquery-list-with-a-fake-iphone/147/) about it, showing it as the iOS contacts app.

The plugin allows you to choose whatever selector you like as the header's. See [this example for more details](http://opensource.teamdf.com/list/examples/demo-australia.html).

Comment: can't get it to work with jQM 1.3.1 - am I missing something? thnx! my call '$('ul#folderlist').list({ headerSelector : 'li.list-first-lvl' });' returns my UL-element. seems right?