# What is that Mobile App effect where as you scroll down and it becomes part of header called?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, effects

I'm building a jQuery Mobile app and when I scroll down through a list I want the mulitple list headings to be become part of the overall header one after another.  I've seen it in several apps, but I don't know what it's called and would love a good plugIn.  Thanks.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296204/sticky-list-dividers-in-jquery-mobile

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is called Sticky Header. Here is a demo http://codepen.io/chrissp26/full/gBrdo

Resource: [Getting a sticky header to "push up", like in Instagram's iPhone app using CSS and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279725/getting-a-sticky-header-to-push-up-like-in-instagrams-iphone-app-using-css-a)

Update 2013/06/11: Also called Persistent Headers. 
Resource: http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/